# Switching variables in a function based on user input

Tags: javascript, arrays, user-input, dna-sequence

I am trying to compare two DNA sequences with wobbles and report mismatches. To explain DNA and wobbles in programming sense, they are strings of characters(bases) A,T,C and G and wobbles are characters assigned to more than one bases e.g. R is 'A' or 'G'.
Here !N in if() condition corresponds to the declared array N. I have to manually edit this each time to change it to !R, !Y, or !K etc in the condition.

```js
const R = ['A', 'G'];
const Y = ['C', 'T'];
const K = ['G', 'T'];
const N = ['A', 'G', 'C', 'T'];
const wob = ['R', 'Y', 'K', 'M', 'S', 'W', 'N']

let mismatchPositions = [];
for (let i = 0; i < referenceLength; i++) {
  if (!N.includes(seq.sequence[i]) && wob.includes(referenceSeq[i]) &&
    referenceSeq[i] !== seq.sequence[i]) {
    const mismatch = `(${i+1} ${referenceSeq[i]} > ${seq.sequence[i]})`;
    mismatchPositions.push(mismatch);
  } else if (!wob.includes(referenceSeq[i]) && referenceSeq[i] !== seq.sequence[i]) {
    const mismatch = `(${i+1} ${referenceSeq[i]} > ${seq.sequence[i]})`;
    mismatchPositions.push(mismatch);
  }
```

I tried putting all the arrays in one variable with flat() but it loses its functionality because there are same bases in few of the wobbles. Is there any way to individually switch the arrays in if() condition from !N to !R and so. I want it make as a user input variable.

Example: for reference sequence:

```
GTAAGTTGNACG
```

Output:

```
GTAAGTTGAATG -(11 C > T Mismatch)
GTAAGTTAAACG -(8 G > A Mismatch)
```

For Mismatch at N it is not showing any mismatch because of the `if()` condition. If the ref-seq had Y or K instead of N it would show mismatch at 9th position.

Comment: do you have some example what it is supposed to do and what it does?

Comment: It is supposed to compare two DNA sequences by each character 
e.g. for A G G C G T N C T G all sequences with A G G G G T T C T G will report 4C>G Mismatch where at 4th position there is a mismatch and in this case where N can tolerate all 4 bases so not a mismatch. If there was an R in the reference sequence the it would give a mismatch at 7th position.

Comment: please add this and some more information (like the `N` ...?) to the question.

Comment: The code is missing a `}`

Comment: @NinaScholz Thanks for the remark I edited the question with more explanation. Yes Barmar thanks for noticing but there is no problem with the code, it runs fine I just want to improve it do that I can switch the variable in the condition dynamically

Comment: please add some more examples what result do you expect? which variables do you like to check against?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are inputting `GTAAGTTGNACG`, which can be either of the four: `GTAAGTTGAACG`, or, `GTAAGTTGGACG`, or `GTAAGTTGCACG`, or `GTAAGTTGTACG`, due to the wobble of N. N acts as a joker card of a sort, and its value can be either `A`, `G`, `C`, or `T`. So, when you input `GTAAGTTGNACG`, you're expecting one of the four outcomes I specified earlier. But, instead of any of them, you're getting `GTAAGTTGAATG`. That is causing a mismatch in the penultimate base - the ending of your outcome should be `CG`, and you're getting `TG`. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

You can declare an object containing the RYKN arrays:

```
const rykn  = {
  R: ['A', 'G'],
  Y: ['C', 'T'],
  K: ['G', 'T'],
  N: ['A', 'G', 'C', 'T']
};
```

As long as you have some string variable containing which of "R", "Y", "K", "N" to use, you can modify your if:

```
if (!N.includes(seq.sequence[i] && ...)
```

to

```
let choice = "R"; // or use a value from a drop down, etc
if (!rykn[choice].includes(seq.sequence[i] && ...)
```

Comment: Thanks @James it works very well I like how a simple change made it work perfectly

Answer (score 1):

You could put the bases into an object and iterate the keys.

```js
const
    compare = (sequence, reference) => {
        const
            bases = { R: 'AG', Y: 'CT', K: 'GT', N: 'AGCT' },
            wob = 'RYKMSWN';

        let mismatchPositions = {};
        for (let i = 0; i < reference.length; i++) {
            if (reference[i] === sequence[i]) continue;
            for (const base in bases) {
                if (!bases[base].includes(sequence[i]) && wob.includes(reference[i])) {
                    (mismatchPositions[base] ??= []).push(`(${i + 1} ${reference[i]} > ${sequence[i]})`);
                }
            }
            if (!wob.includes(reference[i])) {
                (mismatchPositions.wob ??= []).push(`(${i + 1} ${reference[i]} > ${sequence[i]})`);
            }
        }
        return mismatchPositions;
    };
    
console.log(compare('GTAAGTTGAATG', 'GTAAGTTGNACG'));
console.log(compare('GTAAGTTAAACG', 'GTAAGTTGNACG'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks @Nina that's really helpful. I also made the base variable a user input element which I can change accordingly from frontend. Thanks again.